# Create JavaFX8 stage and pass objects to it

Tags: java, javafx

I have a programm with an optional gui, coltrolled by command line args. The programm has a database connection which is needed in both parts, gui and non-gui part.

So how can I create the connection, then create a stage and give the connection to the scenen controller? Either the controller must know the main class, or the main class must know the controller.

I could do this with static variables, but this seems to be ugly.

I also could always start the programm over the `start(Stage stage)`-method. But then I create a stage even when I have a console only programm.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `Application` class forces the FX toolkit to start as soon as it is loaded. So I think you need to structure it something like this:

```
public class DataBaseAccessor {

    // constructor connects to database...

    // provides methods for data access ....

}
```

A GUI startup class:

```
public class MyGuiApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        DataBaseAccessor dbAccessor = new DataBaseAccessor();
        // build UI etc...
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

and a general startup class:

```
public class MyApp {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 1 && "-graphical".equals(args[0])) {
            Application.launch(MyGuiApp.class, args) ;
        } else {
            runWithoutUI();
        }
    }

    private static void runWithoutUI() {
        DataBaseAccessor dbAccessor = new DataBaseAccessor();
        // run without UI....
    }

}
```

Now you can do

```
java MyApp
```

to run without the UI, and

```
java MyApp -graphical
```

to run with it.

Comment: When I do this, there is still a JavaFX Alpplication Thread started.

Comment: Even worse. It wont start on a computer without graphics:

"Failed in XOpenDisplay
(java:30836): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"

Comment: The first surprises me; the second doesn't surprise me given the first. I guess that `Application` has a static initializer that causes the FX toolkit to start up, so if the main class is a subclass of `Application` it forces the toolkit to start (and fails if it can't). I refactored the code so the main class only loads `Application` if needed (requires one small additional class).

Comment: OK, apparently not a static initializer, but the JVM launcher is doing something extra if the main class is a subclass of `Application`. The updated solution still works.